# How do I call an method in an action method in the Controller - Ember

Tags: function, ember.js, methods, action

How can I call `schoolSearchResults` with `searchSchools`? I want to update a list of schools when the action `searchSchools` is called.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    searchSchools: function(){
      //call schoolSearchResults
    }

  },
  schoolSearchResults: function(){
    alert("schoolSearch");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the ember component doc

```
// ember 2
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    searchSchools(){
      this.schoolSearchResults()
    }

  },
  schoolSearchResults(){
    this.sendAction("searchSchools");
  }
});

// ember 1
    export default Ember.Component.extend({
      actions: {
        searchSchools: function(){
          this.schoolSearchResults()
        }

      },
      schoolSearchResults: function(){
        this.send("searchSchools");
      }
    });
```

Comment: For the uninitiated this might look like "10 GOTO 20; 20 GOTO 10", so I'd recommend to read http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_sendAction to get a grasp what is going on. (Hint: It's the parent that gets called, not the current controller/component)

Comment: @okket boro it's just a sample on show ,how to call and action method and how call and method of component, it's no he production or even development code